# iPad apps on MacOS don't start

Tags: macos, ipad, applications, apple-silicon

I have an M1 Mac running macOS Monterrey 12.6.2 (21G320). I've used the App Store to download some iPad apps that say "Designed for iPad" but don't say "Not verified for macOS" (which, I assume, means "have been verified for macOS"). However, for all apps, none of them launch. I've tried many apps in different genres, but two simple examples are: Good Sudoku by Zach Gage and Windy.com.

Double clicking on the app has no effect (no app opens, no crash dialog opens). Similar for clicking on "Open" in the App Store.

Using Console, I see the following:

```
error   10:16:38.307531+0400    CoreServicesUIAgent LAUNCH: RBSLaunchRequest FAILURE <private> net.stfj.goodsudoku <private> 0x0-0x295295 failed with error Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x600002983990 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=80 "Authentication error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}
error   10:16:38.307605+0400    CoreServicesUIAgent LAUNCH: request execute thru runningboard of 0x0-0x295295 net.stfj.goodsudoku/<private> failed with error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10671 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSLaunchWithRunningboard, _LSLine=2732, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002981800 {Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x600002983990 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=80 "Authentication error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}}}
error   10:16:38.312408+0400    CoreServicesUIAgent handle LS launch error: {\n    AppPath = "/Applications/Good Sudoku.app";\n    ErrorCode = "-10671";\n}
error   10:16:38.314187+0400    App Store   [ASDAppLibrary]: Failed to launch <ASDApp: 0x600006f44a50>: {bundleID = net.stfj.goodsudoku; storeItemID = 1489118195; storeCohort = 10|date=1671775200000&sf=143441&pgtp=Genre&pgid=182869&prpg=Genre_25204&ctxt=Play&imptyp=lockup&kind=iosSoftware&lngid=1; storeExternalVersionID = 843039411; update available = NO; path = /Applications/Good Sudoku.app; installed = 1} status: 2
error   10:16:38.314079+0400    appstoreagent   Error when attempting to launch app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The application “Good Sudoku” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/Good%20Sudoku.app/, NSLocalizedDescription=The application “Good Sudoku” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred., NSUnderlyingError=0x141898bc0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10671 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=2732, NSUnderlyingError=0x141884ac0 {Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x14188bfd0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=80 "Authentication error" UserInfo=0x141834460 (not displayed)}}}, _LSFunction=_LSLaunchWithRunningboard}}} : <ASDApp: 0x140792c30>: {bundleID = net.stfj.goodsudoku; storeItemID = 1489118195; storeCohort = 10|date=1671775200000&sf=143441&pgtp=Genre&pgid=182869&prpg=Genre_25204&ctxt=Play&imptyp=lockup&kind=iosSoftware&lngid=1; storeExternalVersionID = 843039411; update avai
default 10:16:38.320772+0400    appstoreagent   MDQuery changed app: <SoftwareItem: 0x1407a6580>: (net.stfj.goodsudoku, 1.0.22, 0:0 md:0x141c112d0 /Applications/Good Sudoku.app)
default 10:16:38.321026+0400    appstoreagent   [FP/net.stfj.goodsudoku/403A3A8F] Will start fairplay recovery with fairplayStatus: -42004
default 10:16:38.739990+0400    appstoreagent   [FP/FP/net.stfj.goodsudoku/403A3A8F] Repair complete with result: 1 error: (null)
```

What are the requirements for running iPad apps on macOS? What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: “Not verified on macOS” is PR speak for “it could work, but is not likely.”  As the developer isn’t claiming compatibility with macOS, and it’s not working, it’s a safe bet that the behavior you’re seeing is expected.

Comment: I suspect the requirement is that you can see it in the AppStore on the Mac and it does NOT have “Not verified on macOS” If the developer says it does not run on macOS then you won't see it in the AppStore

Comment: OK, but can anyone name a single app that works?